# Watir or Selenium webdriver - Find for IMG SRC duplicated

Tags: image, selenium-webdriver, compare, watir-webdriver

Is there any possible way to index/list and compare `<img src="">` values using watir or selenium webdriver?.

Update #1

I've succesfully managed to progress on the general script for finding the right `<div>` that contains the pictures

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

$i = 1

(1..1000).each do |i|
  b.goto 'http:example.com'
  b.div(:id, 'pic_container').wait_until_present
  puts 'div present'

begin
  if

  else

  end

end
b.close
```

There will be more coding, only thing i can't resolve is enumerate all pictures available, comparing their sources and output the results.

---

Update #2

Thanks both JustinKo and Carldmitch for their answers. I went to this now:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto 'https://trafficmonsoon.com'

begin
  Watir::Wait.until { b.url == "http://example.com" }
  b.a(:href, "http://example.com/img").wait_until_present
  b.a(:href, "http://example.com/img").click
  Watir::Wait.until { b.url == "http://example.com/img" }
  b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
  b.a(:class, "btn").click
end

$i = 1

(1..1000).each do |i|
  b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
  pics_set = b.div(:id, 'pics_container').images
  pics_array = []
  pics_set.each_with_index do |image|
    pics_array.push(image.current_src)
  end
  puts pics_array.find_all {|e| pics_array.rindex(e) != pics_array.index(e) }.uniq

end
b.close
```

The only problem here, is that, it is no showing which picture is duplicated, instead of, it only shows all `img src` without the one duplicated. Any hint on this?.

Thanks in advance.

---

Update #3

I got it working, it prints out the duplicated `img src`, but can't use the output data to do some web browser interactions, (clicks & drags)

---

Update #4

I've succesfully managed to interact with the data, only thing i want to know, is there any way to pic one or another duplicated picture?, since both ahve the same `img src`it's impissible to click or drag from that attibute.

Here is the code that i've got by now

```
require 'sub'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

b.goto 'https://example'

begin
  Watir::Wait.until { b.url == "http://example.com/img" }
  b.a(:href, "http://example.com/imgs").wait_until_present
  b.a(:href, "http://example.com/imgs").click
  Watir::Wait.until { b.url == "http://example.com/imgs" }
  b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
  b.a(:class, "btn btn-xs btn-danger").click
end

b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
pics_set = b.div(:id, 'site_loader').images
pics_array = []
pics_set.each_with_index do |image|
  pics_array.push(image.current_src)
end
duplicated = pics_array.find_all {|e| pics_array.rindex(e) != pics_array.index(e) }.uniq
duplicated[0].sub!("http://example.com
b.img(:src, duplicated).click", ".")
```

---

Update #5

Here is an example of the `div`i'm diggin' into

```
<div id="pic_container">
  <img src="./images/test/3.png" style="cursor:pointer;width:64px" onclick="checkClick ("7hva9f")">
  <img src="./images/test/5.png" style="cursor:pointer;width:59px" onclick="checkClick ("xt0nnc")">
  <img src="./images/test/5.png" style="cursor:pointer;width:67px" onclick="checkClick ("1tyz9b")">
  <img src="./images/test/1.png" style="cursor:pointer;width:67px" onclick="checkClick ("300yp7")">
  <img src="./images/test/7.png" style="cursor:pointer;width:67px" onclick="checkClick ("pzxgyh")">
</div>
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what exactly you are looking for. Can you please provide an example - ie HTML, what you are trying to do and what you have tried?

Comment: Sure, i'd like to inspect websites looking for duplicated images by it's source address.

I think that the best way doing this is to inspect, and array/list all diplayed pictures by their source address and then comparing them to see if there is any duplicate.

Right now i'm working on the watir/selenium script, i've successfully managed to run the script searching for single items, but not the array thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the images in a browser or element by retrieving an `ImageCollection`. To get the collection you can either use the `imgs` or `images` method.

All of the images in the "pic_container" div can be retrieved by:

```
b.div(:id, 'pic_container').images
```

The `ImageCollection` is enumerable, which means you can get an array of the src attributes using:

```
b.div(:id, 'pic_container').images.map(&:src)
#=> ['src1', 'src2', 'etc']
```

Or if you need to do more custom logic per image, you can iterate through each one using `each` or `each_with_index` (if you also want an index). For example:

```
b.div(:id, 'pic_container').images.each_with_index do |image, i|
  puts image.src
  puts i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm doing things other than driving the browser, I like to just use Ruby.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto 'http:example.com'

#collects all images on page
image_collection = browser.images

# creates array of the 'src' urls
image_array = []
image_collection.each do |image|
  image_array.push(image.current_src)
end

# outputs urls if any duplicates are found in the array
puts image_array.find_all {|e| image_array.rindex(e) != image_array.index(e) }.uniq 

browser.close
```